# Updated with latest dependencies : Getting Configuration 'compile' is obsolete issue and cannot connect with firebase

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I replaced compile with implementation but still I am getting issue.I tried so Many ways to solve this , but still I didn't get . I didn't get any issue in my Gradle file but I am getting this warning only "Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'." . Because of this I am not able to connect with firebase(Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle Config) .Below is my grade files,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


 android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/mimetypes.default'
    exclude 'META-INF/gfprobe-provider.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/javamail.default.address.map'
    exclude 'META-INF/mailcap.default'
    exclude 'META-INF/mailcap'
    exclude 'META-INF/javamail.charset.map'
    exclude 'META-INF/javamail.default.providers'
    exclude 'META-INF/hk2-locator/default'

   }
 }

dependencies {
ext {
    support_library_version = '28.0.0' //use the version of choice
}
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_library_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${support_library_version}"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:20041127.091804'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.1'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.6'
implementation 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.6'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Project Level Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.3.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 }

 allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
  }

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Probably one of the library (from `dependencies`) is still using `compile`

Comment: @kAliert I already tried this

Comment: @Boken Library means which one ?

Comment: You have to find out which one lead this error by simply remove dependency one by one and sync project with gradle until you find the one. Also multiple depencencies may have compile.

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanian use this **`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`** instead of `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your library is still using `compile`.

For example this library:
`implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'`

In this file:
https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout/blob/master/swipe-reveal-layout/build.gradle

using:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Sure I ll check this and let you know

Comment: What to do in this kind of case ? I need this library. @Boken

Comment: It's only `warning`. You can info library owner/maintainer about problem (or even create pull request for this)

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanian You really don't need to do anything for now. If you have to fix it, you can download the source, modify the build.gradle yourself and add that modified project as a library in your project.

Comment: Found the issue .@Boken Culprit is " classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.3.2'
" After updating to "classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0'" Working perfectly. Thanks @Boken